# Was meint ein Österreicher, wenn er am Telefon fragt "Welche Klappe haben Sie bitte"?

Tags: noun, meaning, austrian

Ich wurde einmal während eines Telefongespräches mit einem österreichischen Kunden überraschend gefragt:

> Welche Klappe haben Sie bitte?

Was wollte er von mir wissen?

---

During a business call with an Austrian customer, he all of a sudden asked me:

> Welche Klappe haben Sie bitte?

What did he want to know from me?

Comment: Zum Glück hat er nicht "Halten Sie die Klappe!" gesagt. ;)

Comment: Was hast du denn bitte geantwortet? Du musst das Gespräch doch weitergeführt haben. Warum hast du nicht nachgefragt?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Unter *Klappe* verstehen Österreicher die Durchwahl einer Telefonnummer.

Das ist normalerweise eine kurze Gruppe von zwei bis maximal vier Ziffern, die der Hauptnummer eines Anschlusses hinzugefügt werden muss, um die gesuchte Person direkt zu erreichen.

Beispiel:

> Unsere allgemeine Firmennummer ist +43 1 998877. Meine Klappe ist 321.

Die Person ist also direkt unter der Nummer +43 1 998877-321 zu erreichen, ohne dass der Anruf durchgestellt werden muss.

Comment: +1 Wir nennen das auch Nebenstelle.

Comment: In Deutschland würde man fragen **welche Durchwahl haben Sie?** oder **Welche Nebenstelle sind Sie**.

Comment: "Apparat" ist auch noch ein allerdings weniger gebräuchlicher Ausdruck.

Comment: Wow, that's good to know if I'm ever in a call with an Austrian. oO

Comment: Witzig, ist mir in all den Telefonaten mit unserem großen österreichischen Kunden nie untergekommen. Die fragen immer nur nach der Durchwahl. Etwas perplex war ich dagegen, als sie eine Stiegenhausschaltung erwähnten und sich nicht vorstellen konnten, dass ich das noch nie gehört hatte :)

Comment: Ist "Stiegenhausschaltung" das Licht im Treppenhaus?

Answer (score 12):

Eine Ergänzung bzw. Richtigstellung der Antwort von splattne:

Eine Klappe ist, wie schon von splattne richtig beantwortet, die Durchwahlnummer oder Nebenstelle.

Sie ist in Österreich aber nicht auf zwei bis vier Ziffern beschränkt, sondern kann auch nur 1 Ziffer haben (die Klappe 0 ist häufig die Klappe der Vermittlung), oder kann auch auch 5 oder mehr Ziffern lang sein. So haben z.B. die Telefonapparate im AKH Wien (Allgemeines Krankenhaus der Stadt Wien) fünfstellige Klappen.

**Zur Herkunft des Begriffs:**

In den Anfangszeiten der Telefonie wurden Telefongespräche von Hand vermittelt. Man drehte eine Kurbel am Fernsprechapparat, wodurch Strom in einer Leitung induziert wurde, der in der Vermittlungsstelle eine Klingel zum Läuten brachte. Das »Fräulein vom Amt« hat sich dann selbst mit dem Anrufer verbunden, der ihr mündlich mitteilte, wen er anrufen wollte. Daraufhin hat die Vermittlerin (es waren fast ausschließlich Frauen) ihrerseits beim gewünschten Empfänger angeläutet. Falls dieser das Gespräch angenommen hat, hat das Fräulein vom Amt dann eine Steckverbindung auf einem Kasten hergestellt, womit Anrufer und Empfänger verbunden waren.

Dieser Kasten hieß »Klappenschrank«. Der Stromstoß des Anrufers hat nämlich nicht nur die Klingel aktiviert, sondern hat auch bewirkt, dass eine Klappe, welche die Anschlussbuchse des Anrufers verdeckt hat, aufklappte und dessen Anschluss freigab. Dadurch sah die vermittelnde Person sofort, von welcher *Klappe* der Anruf kam. Um die Verbindung herzustellen, musste sie nun nur noch die Klappe des Empfängers aufklappen um dann die Verbindung herzustellen.

Es war also jeder Fernsprecher mit einer nummerierten Klappe identifiziert, und der Anrufer musste dem Fräulein nur die Klappe des gewünschten Empfängers nennen.

Die Technik hat sich geändert, aber die Nummern sind bis heute geblieben, und heißen mancherorts eben auch heute noch »Klappen«. Allerdings ist dieser Begriff auch in Österreich mittlerweile rar geworden.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, Welche Klappe haben Sie bitte? means "what is your extension?"

And the sense is, what differentiates your phone line from the company's main line?